# git revert deleted files in master, keep feature working files intact

Tags: git, revert, git-flow

While working in a local 'myfeature' branch, I deleted some files and committed them locally.  Along the way, those commits were then merged with remote origin/master.  I needed to get those deleted files back, so I did a `git pull` for the latest on master and cut a 'hotfix' branch where I:

```
git revert <commit id>
```

in reverse chronological order of those bad commits and got those deleted files back.  I'm basing on the git-flow branching model so correct me if I'm wrong, I should now merge the 'hotfix' into master, as well as any 'release' branches, develop, and any other 'feature' branches?

Do I need to do anything to my currently still in-progress 'myfeature' branch where I want to keep those said files deleted?  Will those files stay deleted once I merge 'myfeature' or will those files resurrect when I merge?

I'm not using git-flow, just the model.

Answer (score 1):

About getting back deleted files :

If your history looks like this :

```
* aa1234 last commit
* bb2345 commit
* cc3456 commit
* dd4567 deleted fileC dirD/fileD & made other changes
* ee5678 deleted filA  dirB/fileB & made other changes
* ff6789 commit
```

and you want to get back file A,B,C,D as they were when you deleted them, you can check them out one by one, using `git checkout <hash> -- <path/to/file>`:

```
git checkout ee5678 -- fileA
git checkout ee5678 -- dirB/fileB
git checkout dd4567 -- fileC dirD/fileD
```

That way, you keep your other modifications safe.

About the flow : I didn't quite get which flow you are using, but if you create a commit whose action is to recreate the files you have deleted, then yes, merging this commit in other branches will apply the same action.

Comment: I thought about using git checkout, but it's a series of directories and files, but git revert seemed to do the trick.  In 'myfeature' the files need to stay deleted, since I reverted them in 'master', will 'myfeature' remove those files again when I finally decide to merge them into 'master' or will they still exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you revert commits then yes, all changes of that commit are reverted, but other than that nothing else. So if you *bad* changes are isolated within commits, you can simply revert those while leaving the good commits in place.

If you however have commits where good and bad actions are mixed, then you would also lose those good actions when reverting them like that, so I’d suggest you not to do that.

Instead you should do partial reverts. In general you have more control over the reverts, when doing them with the `-n` flag. That way Git won’t create a reverting commit for you and you can manipulate the changes first and then commit it yourself. In addition this allows you to make multiple reverts at once. So ideally when there are multiple commits that together introduced a change you no longer want, you can revert them all in a single commit to fix it.

Comment: My reverted bad commits will only be in master.  I guess the overall question is, since I deleted those files in 'myfeature' do I run the risk of them not being removed once I merge in 'myfeature' - the branch where I need them removed?  Does git know that they should stay deleted?

Comment: No, Git won’t know that. When you edit a file in `master`, delete the same file in a branch and merge that branch into `master` later, you’ll get a merge conflict as Git won’t be able to figure out what to do. So you’d need to resolve those conflicts then.

Comment: I think I'm the other way around.  I deleted in feature, deleted in master, restored in master, but needs to remain deleted in feature and when I merge into master.